# app engine java mail not sent

Tags: java, email, google-app-engine

I am experiencing a strange behavior with Java Mail App Engine: it looks like the mail is sent depending on the content of the mail (the rest of the mail - sender, receiver - being fixed). However, up to now I have not been able to identify which parameter in the content is responsible for that ( specific character, mail length, line length, ......). My mails are in french.
My mails are pretty simple (some lines of plain text with escape characters) and http link.
When looking at traces, I can see that sendmail function has been requested, but I don't know how to go deeper into the analysis.
I am way below my quota. 
I also have checked that no exception are raised when sending the mail.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: can you check if the difference is the presence in the msg body of a link to the app's `appspot.com` domain or not?